# Cumulative distribution function vs. Probability

Tags: probability

I've got cumulative distribution function, which fragment is: $F_X(t) = 0 $ for $t <-1 $, $ F_X(t)= 0.5 \cdot (t+1)$ for $-1\le t<0$ and $F_X(t) = 0.75$ for $0 \le t<4$. I am to find $P(-1 < x < 0)$. It should be something like $0.5(\epsilon+1) - 0$ where $\epsilon$ is close to $0$? Or how should I write it?

Comment: hint: $P(a < X < b) = F(b−) − F(a)$

Comment: Ok, so it's just $0.5$, yes?

Comment: If we want to write formally, $\Pr(X\lt 0)=\lim_{t\to 0^-}F_X(t)$.